# Getting keystates in linux

Tags: python, linux, language-agnostic, macros, keyboard

So I'm trying to make my `Capslock` key into `Escape` when it's tapped, and `Control` when it's used with another key in.

How can I watch the keystates for X? Vim says the files in /dev/input aren't files, which is weird, and I can't `cat` them.

I tried this python code snippet but it freezes on `read()`:

```
KBD=open("/dev/input/event0",'rb')
event=KBD.read(72)
```

I'm open to other ideas too. `autokey`, `xbindkeys`, `xmacro`, etc (although I've tried these with no luck).

Edit: This is for X windows running in Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in console mode or X windows? The answer is completely different depending on this.

Comment: X windows. I updated my question.